# how do I get the ip from the distributor?

Tags: ip

working on a project where im making a firm, I need to get everything IT related ready for the firm.

In the office of the firm there are two employers, even if the firm expands that amount wont get much bigger. the firm doesnt have a server they only have one router and two pc's.

So when i buy broadband from a company, do i just tell them what IP i want and how many?

and how do i figure out what ip to use when i only need a max of 10 ip's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ISP will allocate IP addresses.  Since you have no servers, you will have a small allocation and most likely, your PCs will be NATted.  Your ISP will give you the details.